# When using Codebuild for sub branch,

Tags: aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

I have `Codecommit` and `Codebuild`.

Normally `Codebuild` is trigger automtically by push `master` branch to `Codecommit`.

Now, I push new branch (temp_fix) to `Codecommit` , but `Codebuild` is not automatically triggered.

So, I try to start new build button and write `refs/heads/temp_fix` in source version optional input text box.

Then this error occurs

```
[Container] 2022/11/21 09:46:48 going inside waitForAgent
[Container] 2022/11/21 09:46:48 Waiting for agent ping
[Container] 2022/11/21 09:46:49 Waiting for DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
BucketRegionError: incorrect region, the bucket is not in 'ap-northeast-1' region at endpoint ''
    status code: 301, request id: , host id:  for primary source and source version refs/heads/temp_fix
```

How can I build with the another branch not `master` ?

Answer (score 0):

The CodeBuild configuration can only define the default behavior of:

- "what git event is triggering (in your case, it is 'commit to master')"
- "what git reference to build from (in your case, it is the 'master branch')

Sadly the default configuration doesn't allow you to implement "if else" logic to full fill your needs.

If you want to add a dynamic rule to custom the trigger and build rules, **the correct way is to enable CodeCommit and CodeBuild notification, and let the notifcation send to SNS topic then Lambda, and use Lambda to analysis the event to determine what branch / commit id / tag to build from.**

For example, you can write a python function like this:

```
def codecommit_event_handler(event):
    if (
        (event["branch"] in ["master", "your-magic-branch"])
        or (
            event["branch"].startswith("dev")
        )
    ):
        ... then trigger build
```

I happened to have an open source solution for this, https://github.com/MacHu-GWU/aws_ci_bot-project you are responsible to write a short python function using IF, ELSE logic to decide: "based on the given CodeCommit event, which branch I should build from". For example:

- you can customize this `do_we_trigger_build`  function to determine whether you want to trigger a build: https://github.com/MacHu-GWU/aws_ci_bot-project/blob/main/aws_ci_bot/codecommit_and_codebuild.py#L107
- you can customize this `run_build_job` function to determine which branch, commit id, tag id you want to build from, based on the CodeCommit event you received: https://github.com/MacHu-GWU/aws_ci_bot-project/blob/main/aws_ci_bot/codecommit_and_codebuild.py#L222